# Django filter on generic relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model below which points to a generic relationship. This can either be a contact object or a customer object.

```
class Unsubscribe(models.Model):
    """
    Notes:
    See: http://www.screamingatmyscreen.com/2012/6/django-and-generic-relations/
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, help_text="Represents the name of the model")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text="stores the object id")
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    reason = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    request_made = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   help_text="Shows when object was created.")


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-request_made']
```

I would like to list out all unsubscribed, both unsubscribed customers and contacts only for the user.

```
 queryset = Unsubscribe.objects.filter()
```

Above gives me all unsubscribe customers and contacts for any users normally I would solve this by doing....

```
queryset = Unsubscribe.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

However, Unsubscribe object does not have a user, but both customers and contacts do.

So how can I filter on the generic relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this

```
Unsubscribe.objects.filter(content_type__name='user', user=request.user)
```

For `content_type__name='user'` specify name of your model class for user or whatever you have associated it with.

Or this also

```
Unsubscribe.objects.filter(content_type__name='user', object_id=request.user.id)
```

Comment: I tired this also  queryset = Unsubscribe.objects.filter(content_object__contact_owner=self.request.user) but it states content_object does not exist, when it does.

Comment: I don't think `content_obect__...` is valid field lookup, try using as I specified.

Answer (score 4):

I assume your model is like:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
   ...
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

You can get all the contacts related to the current user using:

```
contact_ids = [each.id for each in request.user.contact_set.all()]
```

You can get all the unsubscribed contacts for that user:

```
unsubscribed_contacts = Unsubscribe.objects.filter(content_type__name='contact', object_id__in=contact_ids)
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that a generic foreign key is just two fields, one that is a ForeignKey to a ContentType model, and the other which is the primary key of whichever model you're pointing to.  So, to be more generic, you could do something like this:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
Unsubscribe.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, object_id=user.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

For newcomers to this question that have newer Django versions, `content_type__name` is just a property and you can't query with that. Instead use `content_type__model` in your filter methods just like that:

```
Unsubscribe.objects.filter(content_type__model='user', user=request.user)
```